# Allowing bound Timespan data entry to Access database field

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, event-handling

I am trying to allow the user to enter hours and minutes into a textbox-like control (winforms) that binds to a dataset that is tied to an Access database. I am currently using a field that stores the total number of minutes instead of using a date/time field because I need just the hours and minutes, and not the number of days included.

In other words, I want the user to be able to enter in the format `HH:mm`, with the hours being greater than 23 (100 for example) so that it looks like `100:30` (100 hours, 30 minutes) when they enter it, but when it saves to the underlying table, it would be the total number of minutes (6030). In addition, a Null value should also be allowed.

I am flexible on how it is stored in the database, but Access does not have a TimeSpan field type, and the DateType field type limits the number of hours to 23, so that is why I chose a Long Integer value of minutes.

There has to be a way to do this, but after much searching I cannot find anything that gives me a viable solution that allows for hours being more than 23.

My initial thought would be to allow the user to enter anything into a normal textbox, then have code that parses it on the change event and turns it into minutes (if valid), setting that value to a hidden textbox that is what is actually bound to the datatable, but there are lots of problems with parsing what is entered and it seems like there should be something much easier. I tried using a DateTimePicker using only time format, but it will not allow hours greater than 23.

Could someone please give me some advice on how to achieve this?

As a last resort, I will probably just end up changing the field to a Single and let them enter `100.5` for 100 hours and 30 minutes, but it would still be preferable for it be entered as `100:30`

---

**EDIT:**

My apologies for not fully following the answer, but I am getting several errors about

> Value is not a member of EventArgs

and

> 'AddMinutes' is not a member of 'TimeSpan'.

---

**EDIT:**

I am MUCH closer now... thank you for teaching me something very useful.

I had to change the code inside the handlers so I could understand it. It's not as fancy as yours, but it works:

```
Private Sub Binding_Format(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If e.Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
        Dim hours As Integer = e.Value \ 60
        Dim minutes As Integer = e.Value - (hours * 60)
        e.Value = CType(hours, String) & ":" & CType(minutes, String)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Binding_Parse(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    If e.Value IsNot DBNull.Value Then
        Dim parts As String() = e.Value.Split(":"c)
        If parts.GetUpperBound(0) = 1 Then
            If IsNumeric(parts(0)) And IsNumeric(parts(1)) And
               parts(0).ToString.Length > 0 And parts(1).ToString.Length > 0 Then
                e.Value = CInt(parts(0) * 60) + CInt(parts(1))
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The very last problem I have it that when the form initially loads/binds, it does not run `Binding_Format` and shows the integer instead. If I click on a different row in the grid, the textbox will update correctly from then on.

**EDIT:**

That problem was fixed by moving the handler code to happen before I fill the Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just bind a `TextBox` as you always do and then handle the `Format` and `Parse` events of the `Binding`. That will allow you to convert between `TimeSpan` and `String` and back again.

I haven't tested this code but, assuming the data is valid, I believe that these event handlers should work:

```
Private Sub Binding_Format(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    Dim time = DirectCast(e.Value, TimeSpan)

    'Convert from TimeSpan to String.
    e.Value = $"{CInt(Math.Floor(time.TotalHours)):#00}:{time.Minutes:00}"
End Sub

Private Sub Binding_Parse(sender As Object, e As ConvertEventArgs)
    Dim text = CStr(e.Value)
    Dim parts = text.Split(":"c)

    'Convert from String to TimeSpan.
    e.Value = TimeSpan.FromHours(CInt(parts(0))) + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(CInt(parts(1)))
End Sub
```

You can hook them up along these lines:

```
Dim binding = timeTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myDataSource, "TimeColumnOrProperty")

AddHandler binding.Format, AddressOf Binding_Format
AddHandler binding.Parse, AddressOf Binding_Parse
```

You may need to call `binding.ReadValue()` after attaching the event handlers if the data has already been written to the control without formatting but I haven't tested that either.

Comment: Code example added.

Comment: This at least gives me something to work with. I think the piece I was missing was the `AddHandler` concept, which i am not familiar with, being somewhat of a novice at this. I'm trying to figure out where to put each thing now.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I updated my question with my attempt, but am still having some trouble. Would you be able to explain what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: My apologies. That's what I get for not writing my code in VS. The `e` parameters were the wrong type and the code to build the `TimeSpan` was wrong. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Going to consider this answered, even tho I still need it to work on form load. I can write a kludge as a workaround, but it still would be nice to do it the "right way" if possible.

Comment: It may be because the control has already been populated once before you attach the event handlers. You might be able to fix that by calling `ReadValue` on the `Bindinging` after attaching the event handlers. If not, I'd suggest posting a new question relating to that and providing all and only the information relevant to it.

Comment: By the way, don't forget to detach the event handlers when you're done with the binding. You should always have a `RemoveHandler` for every `AddHandler`.

Comment: that was the problem... the order... thanks, as custom event handlers are a new thing for me

Comment: does "done with the binding" mean to put `RemoveHandler` code on the `Form_Closing` event? They are used as long as the form is open.

Comment: "Done with" means not intending to use any more so the `FormClosing` event handler is certainly an option for where to put the code.

Comment: Thanks again. This has helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You should still use a datetime, even if you only care about minutes. The reason then is you can use all of the built in functions to get days, minutes, seconds. And you can use the built in functions to add minutes etc.

And better yet, you can display/get the start time, and the end time, and go past midnight. 
It is possible that you ONLY need minutes and a raw minutes amount, but in my experience this is a rare need. I mean, if this was ONLY minutes, then just a simple integer column would suffice and you would have thought of that.

So, you should have (we assume) a start and end time.

And if the user is to ONLY enter minutes, then you STILL can and should use a start and end time. And the fact that you have and can use the timespan in .net VERY much supports this idea.

> > I cannot find anything that gives me a viable solution that allows for hours being more than 23.

Why?

If the person enter 5 hours, then you have a start of 0, and a end time of 5 hours.

If they want to enter 200 hours, then you have a start of 0, and a end time of 200 hours later. The beauty of this then you can get days, or minutes or seconds, or even weeks out of the span that represents the start and end time. By using a datetime column then you can easy span over a number of days.

How you display the UI is up to you. When you pull the start + end time, you convert it to minutes, and then display the minutes in a box for the user to edit. When you save, you convert the minutes back to a start time (0) (and a date) and the end time in the future (again, it will have a date part too). That end time could be enough hours for a whole year - one should not care one bit.

The advantage of above is that all reporting (sorting) and even grouping can now work.

And I really cannot imagine an application in which JUST 40 hours are to be entered, but some date is not ALSO part of this mix. As I stated, if you JUST need minutes, then use a integer field.

So, including the start date here seems to be RATHER valuable. It is FAR MORE of a mess and work to deal with minutes and ALSO have to deal with a separate date column.

So the start and end date (with time) columns does not have to be displayed. But, your UI can pull these two values, and then create a timespan var, and your code etc. will thus enjoy the benefits of the many .net routines. And you can thus use many features in the database as a result.

So, say give me all hours for the 3rd week of the year. That query will be FAR more easy if you only dealing with two columns (start and end time). You can thus query a date range and time as a result. So while your code logic will cost you a wee bit more to convert between start/end columns to the one timespan, everything else is far more valuable and flexible here.

So from a logical point of view? A start time column and end time column that includes the date makes sense.

From a physical (UI display) point of view you can pull the two values, get the minutes, and display for user to edit/enter the minutes. When you save back to the database, you reverse the conversion back to the start and end time column.

So, if I enter today 50 hours, then the start time is today (0 time), and then end time will be + 50 hours (in the future). The beauty of this is I can now without code get/calculate/display the future date of having just entered 50 hours. So, now your conversion of hours to future dates is automatic and can even be displayed in reports etc., and done so without additional code.
It also means you can sum() minutes by  using SQL query + sum commands (and datediff) etc.

Since you brought timespan into this discussion? Well, that means days, hours etc. Since the timespan can cover minutes into days etc.? Well, while the datetime column is NOT just days, minutes, seconds, it CAN BE thought as the same data structure when you convert a start date/time and a end date/time to a .net timespan.

So:
Grab start date/time column
Grab end date/time column

Now covert above to a timespan (days, hours, minutes).
Now display, allow user to edit or enter 35 hours.

Now, 
convert back to the start date (no time), and then end date/time is + days, hours, minutes, seconds. You  can thus always get the minutes out of these two columns - but they are stored as a starting date (0 time) and a end date into the future. This will thus allow you to get the minutess,but also seconds, or days or whatever.

On a conceptual level you do have a one to one conversion here. If the date is never to be part of this, and you don't have/need a separate date field, then you can just store this as a simple integer of minutes. But, a start/end datetime column will allow far greater ease in reporting, and also has a one to one conceptual conversion to a .net timespan (without a date).

Comment: well, yeah, but i dont want it in days. I needed a time duration measured in hours and minutes, even if it was more than 24 hours.

Comment: If I could get the date time picker to allow me to enter/display 100 hours in the hours slot, i would love that too, but that sounded like a much more daunting task.

Comment: But a start and enddate time gives you any units of time you so desire. You don't have to care about the units. To be fair, you want hours, but don't' really matter.  Either way, you need a UI that allows more then 24 hours - but that is a 100% separate issue since you can't use the timepicker anyway. You have to roll your UI widget, or whatever, but that changes next to nothing in that a start timedate and a end timedate gives you a means to store that value in a way that is flexible.  Storing the value this way give the best flexibility. You can't use the timepicker anyway.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying, but in this case there is no exact start or end time. it's an estimate of how many hours and minutes a certain task would take. Yes, i could just have them enter it as a float/single and be done with it, but i wanted it to match the other parts of the application that allowed them to enter it in that format. The other answer does exactly what I wanted it to do anyway, with the exception of it not formatting when it does the initial bind. If you have any suggestions for that I would love  to hear them.

Comment: That's fair. It might still be worth it to use two fields (datetime) and just assume that the date part is always zero. My bets are still to use two datetime fields. The date part would thus always be 0 and you don't worry. However, the advantages  is you can still use built in functions like Hours(), minutes() and use datediff() to spit out time units. And you can still format HH:MM:SS etc on the resulting value. And it will have awareness of days for a given time span. However, you are leaning towards just a value in a field. One could build a custom format for a given decimal value (hours)